# Forecast Confidence Interval from bsts package much wider than auto.arima in forecast

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian, forecasting

I recently read up about the bsts package by Steven Scott at Google for Bayesian Structural Time Series model and wanted to give it a shot against the auto.arima function from forecast package that I have been using for a variety of forecasting tasks.

I tried it on a few examples and was impressed with the efficiency of the package as well as the point forecast. But when I looked at the forecast variance I almost always found that bsts ended up giving a much wider confidence band as compared to that of auto.arima. Here is a sample code on a white noise data

```
library("forecast")
library("data.table")
library("bsts")
truthData = data.table(target = rnorm(250))
freq = 52
ss = AddGeneralizedLocalLinearTrend(list(), truthData$target)
ss = AddSeasonal(ss, truthData$target, nseasons = freq)
tStart = proc.time()[3]
model = bsts(truthData$target, state.specification = ss, niter = 500)
print(paste("time taken: ", proc.time()[3] - tStart))
burn = SuggestBurn(0.1, model)
pred = predict(model, horizon = 2 * freq, burn = burn, quantiles = c(0.10, 0.90))

## auto arima fit
max.d = 1; max.D = 1; max.p = 3; max.q = 3; max.P = 2; max.Q = 2; stepwise = FALSE
dataXts = ts(truthData$target, frequency = freq)
tStart = proc.time()[3]
autoArFit = auto.arima(dataXts, max.D = max.D, max.d = max.d, max.p = max.p, max.q = max.q, max.P = max.P, max.Q = max.P, stepwise = stepwise)
print(paste("time taken: ", proc.time()[3] - tStart))
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
plot(pred, ylim = c(-5, 5))
plot(forecast(autoArFit, 2 * freq), ylim = c(-5, 5))
```

Here is the plot
[image: forecast variance bsts top panel auto.arima lower panel]
I was wondering if someone could shed some light on this behavior and how we could control for the forecast variance. As far as I recall from Dr. Hyndman's papers auto.arima's forecast variance calculation do not account for the parameter estimation variance, i.e. the variance in estimated ar and ma coefficients. Is that the driving reason for the discrepancy I see here or are there other subtle points that I am missing and can be controlled for by some parameters.

Thanks

Here is a script to test the inclusion probabilities for short to medium range forecasting problem comparing bsts to auto.arima

```
library("forecast")
library("data.table")
library("bsts")
set.seed(1234)
n = 260
freq = 52
h = 10
rep = 50
max.d = 1; max.D = 1; max.p = 2; max.q = 2; max.P = 1; max.Q = 1; stepwise = TRUE
containsProb = NULL
for (i in 1:rep) {
    print(i)
    truthData = data.table(time = 1:n, target = rnorm(n))
    yTrain = truthData$target[1:(n - h)]
    yTest = truthData$target[(n - h + 1):n]

    ## fit bsts model
    ss = AddLocalLevel(list(), truthData$target)
    ss = AddSeasonal(ss, truthData$target, nseasons = freq)
    tStart = proc.time()[3]
    model = bsts(yTrain, state.specification = ss, niter = 500)
    print(paste("time taken: ", proc.time()[3] - tStart))
    pred = predict(model, horizon = h, burn = SuggestBurn(0.1, model), quantiles = c(0.10, 0.90))
    containsProbBs = sum(yTest > pred$interval[1,] & yTest < pred$interval[2,]) / h

    ## auto.arima model fit
    dataTs = ts(yTrain, frequency = freq)
    tStart = proc.time()[3]
    autoArFit = auto.arima(dataTs, max.D = max.D, max.d = max.d, max.p = max.p, max.q = max.q, max.P = max.P, max.Q = max.P, stepwise = stepwise)
    print(paste("time taken: ", proc.time()[3] - tStart))
    fcst = forecast(autoArFit, h = h)

    ## inclusion probabilities for 80% CI
    containsProbBs = sum(yTest > pred$interval[1,] & yTest < pred$interval[2,]) / h
    containsProbAr = sum(yTest > fcst$lower[,1] & yTest < fcst$upper[,1]) / h
    containsProb = rbindlist(list(containsProb, data.table(bs = containsProbBs, ar = containsProbAr)))
}
colMeans(containsProb)
>  bs   ar 
 0.79 0.80 
c(sd(containsProb$bs), sd(containsProb$ar))
> [1] 0.13337719 0.09176629
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that the BSTS model is nonstationary, while the ARIMA model selected in this case is stationary (actually just white noise). For the BSTS model, the prediction intervals continue to widen over the forecast horizon, while the ARIMA model has constant prediction intervals. For the first forecast horizon, they are relatively close, but they diverge for longer horizons.

Comment: Dear Dr. Hyndman thanks for your response. That makes it very clear that we are paying for the added flexibility of the state-space type of models through the wider CI's for long term forecasting. I did a quick test to validate this for short term (10 period) forecasts and the inclusion probabilities for the 80% CI from bsts model are quite close to the advertised limits. I have added the code as an edit to my original comment.

Comment: I would not say that the BSTS models are more flexible. They are nonstationary by design, whereas the ARIMA models can be nonstationary or stationary. The ARIMA prediction intervals are known to be too narrow, as are many other time series models, not so much because they ignore parameter uncertainty but because they ignore model uncertainty. BSTS models approximate model uncertainty by allowing all components to be nonstationary.